# barplot labels in R: add horizontal lines below the plot region

Tags: r, bar-chart

My code:

```
x <- c(10, 50, 20, 40)
barplot(x, names.arg=LETTERS[1:4])
```

What I want is:

[image]

I made this figure with the help of R and Adobe Acrobat. I am wondering can I obtain this figure using pure R code?

Comment: Could [this link](http://www.researchgate.net/post/R_draw_lines_underneath_X-axis_labels_to_indicate_groups2) help?

Comment: @Pascal It's useful. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add text with `mtext`

```
mtext("E", side = 1, line = 3, adj = 0.375)
mtext("F", side = 1, line = 3, adj = 0.875)
```

and then draw line with `lines` but indicating `xpd=T`

```
lines(c(0,3.5),c(-10,-10),xpd=TRUE)
lines(c(3.8,4.8),c(-10,-10),xpd=TRUE)
```

However, you need manually adjust it.
[image]

Comment: In R or RStudion, if I zoom in or zoom out the figure generated, it would go wrong. The horizontal line below the plot would go away.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pascal. I got another answer.

```
x <- c(10, 50, 20, 40)
barplot(x, names.arg=LETTERS[1:4])

mtext("E", side = 1, line = 3, adj = 0.375)
mtext("F", side = 1, line = 3, adj = 0.875)

axis(1, at=c(0.5,1,2,3,3.3), line=2.5, tick=T, labels=rep("",5), lwd=2, lwd.ticks=0)
axis(1, at=4+c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),line=2.5,tick=T,labels=rep("",5), lwd=2, lwd.ticks=0)
```

[image]